# How Can I Attend Multiple Files To A File Input In HTML And ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I am trying to make a file system for my website and I this file input to hold multiple files.

I tried to put the files in a folder and put the directory on file input's value but it did not work. How can I solve this ?

(You can also comment solutions with NodeJS file system.)

```
<div id="input-div-2"><input id="program-input" required type="file" value="/6/"  name="file input"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple files with <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593225/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1):

just add `multiple` attribute to your input like

```
 <div id="input-div-2"><input multiple id="program-input" required type="file" value="/6/"  name="file"></div>
```

---

UPDATE

---

based on comments you want to set multiple files onto html input element, you should do that using js

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.files = `ArrayOfImages`;
```

Comment: I am not trying to make multiple uploads .I am trying to make giving multiple files to a file input.

Comment: possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249065/js-create-input-type-file-multiple-and-set-js-array-as-value