# How do I control the presentation of number of blocks by using javascript

Tags: javascript

encountered this problem and hope someone could help me out here.

Now I have this html script that allows the user to input title and caption for the images.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="allow_upload">
    <label for="upload_new">Upload Images</label>
 </p>
 <p>
     <label for="image_title">Title: </label>
     <input type="text" name="image_title">
 </p>
 <p>
     <label for="image_caption">Caption: </label>
     <input type="text" name="image_caption" id="image_caption">
 </p>
</form>
```

And I want to control the number of these blocks to be displayed base on the number of images uploaded.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var cbox = document.getElementById('allow_upload');
cbox.style.display = 'block';
var uploadImage = document.getElementById('upload_new');
uploadImage.onclick = function () {
    var image_id = document.getElementById('image_id');
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
    var sel = uploadImage.checked;
    image_id.disabled = sel;
    image.parentNode.style.display = sel ? 'block' : 'none';
    caption.parentNode.style.display = sel ? 'block' : 'none';
    image.disabled = !sel;
    caption.disabled = !sel;
}
```

Thank u stackoverflowers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of frameworks available for this.

You might be interested in the [jQuery File Upload Demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html).

This post is also related to your question.
[How to upload multiple files using one file input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726439)