# How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP

Tags: php

I am doing this with single files uploads using

```
<input type="file" name="comment_img1">
<input type="file" name="comment_img2">
<input type="file" name="comment_img3">
<input type="file" name="comment_img4">
<input type="file" name="comment_img5">
```

However, I am having trouble doing uploading more than one at a time.

For example, I'd like to be able to select a series of images, then upload them to the server, all at once.

It would be great to use a single file input control, if possible.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Directly you can't do multiselect like this. You might check this: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: _"It would be great to use a single file input control, if possible."_ - then it would be great if you could type `single file input control multiple` or similar into google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do multiselect with single input without javascript directly.

However, you might consider using a library for this.

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ 
This one is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is already answered here: [How to upload multiple files using one file input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726439/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-one-file-input-element)

Greetings from Germany

Comment: You should flag it as a duplicate and add a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple attribute for input tag

```
<input type="file" name="images" multiple>
```

so it will allow you to select multiple files and on the server side you will get an array eg: `$_FILES[images]`

then you can loop through this array and upload them one by one

if you still have any confusion see this question [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can't select more than one file in a single input file type without using `multiple` attribute of it.

Use of `multiple` in `input type="file"` is more easy in comparison of your code.
so just use the following :

```
<input type="file" name="whatever_you_want[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

after submit your form data, you will get an array of it like

```
$_FILES['name_of_your_input_file_type'];
```

and after that you can use `foreach loop` to get images in sequence.